# Ray tracing a three-way intersection

Tags: waves, acoustics, geometric-optics

I've been studying ray tracing in media with linear velocity-depth functions. One of the key concepts I've come across is the *ray parameter*, and in particular the idea that the ray parameter is constant along across refraction, reflection, etc.

My question is how this applies in the following case:

[image: Dipping reflector in linear velocity-depth medium]

Here we have a background velocity which increases with depth and a high-velocity reflector in the bottom-left. At the reflection point, then, there will be a three-way interface between the depth-dependent velocity of the background medium and the reflector. It is not clear to me how Snell's Law applies in this case.

My best guess is this:

- As we follow along ray $A$, we see a series of infinitesimal boundaries as the velocity changes with depth. We can treat each of these using Snell's Law to derive the curved path we see here.
- When we reach the reflection point, we can look at the situation like this: As we zoom in to the reflection point, the depth-dependent velocity changes get smaller but the red reflector does not. In the infinitesimal case, then, we need only treat the red reflector. Thus, we see that the angles $a$ and $b$ should be equal.
- Continuing along ray $B$, we once again apply Snell's Law to the depth-dependent velocity to derive a curved path back to the surface.

The problem is, I don't think the ray parameter will be the same for rays $A$ and $B$ in this case.

[Baerg](http://www.crewes.org/ForOurSponsors/ResearchReports/1991/1991-27.pdf) suggests a geometric interpretation of the ray parameter, namely: For a medium with depth-dependent velocity $v = v_0 + kz$, the ray with parameter $p$ follows a circle with radius $R = 1 / pk$ and center $(X_c, Z_c)$. We also have $Z_c = -v_0 / k$, so all rays in the same medium will have the same $Z_c$. Thus, if the rays $A$ and $B$ have the same ray parameter, they must be sections of two circles with the same radius and with centers lying along the same horizontal line. Looking at the diagram above, I do not think this can be the case. Since $Z_c$ depends only on the depth-dependent velocity, I think the ray parameter must be different for these two rays.

And that's where I see a problem... If the ray parameter is invariant through reflection, refraction etc., can it be true that the two segments in this reflection have different ray parameters?

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact meaning of "ray parameter".  There are many conserved quantities in this case since there is a high degree of symmetry.  This could refer to a purely mathematical conservation law, or a physical quantity.  It was not clear from the context.  Also, where is the 3-way interface in your figure?

Comment: The ray parameter is as defined here: http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/RayParameter.html. We can imagine the medium with depth-dependent velocity as a series of infinitesimal 2-way interfaces along horizontal boundaries. If we apply a constant ray parameter to such a model, we get the curved ray paths shown above. However, when we add the angled high-velocity boundary, we now have a third interface--i.e., each point along the boundary "sees" the high velocity medium as well as a horizontal boundary with infinitesimal velocity change.

Comment: Is the sloped bottom moving?  The nature of the boundary does not affect the propagation in the medium (just the resetting of direction upon reflection).  In underwater acoustics such a sloped boundary is handled in ray trace codes.  Snell's law is a statement about symmetry in the medium, the boundary does break the symmetry of the problem overall but within the medium Snell's law still holds.  In fact the "circular ray paths" you mention come from Snell's law.  You don't need to imagine the infinitesimal 2-way interface as in optics as Snell's law holds in the continuum.

Comment: There is a rich history of this in the acoustics literature.  If you comment again I'll post a list of references that may help.  Including ray traces in depth dependent environments with range dependent boundaries.

Comment: I think perhaps I should clarify what I'm asking in the question above... Baerg's suggested geometric interpretation of the ray parameter gives a different value for segment A and segment B in the model above. Since the ray parameter is supposed to be constant through reflection and refraction, it's not clear to me why its value changes in this example.

Comment: "Since the ray parameter is supposed to be constant through reflection and refraction".  Double check this statement for any restrictions on boundary geometry and symmetry.